# Gremlin/Groovy groupCount results

Tags: groovy, neo4j, gremlin

I'm a bit stumped with `groupCount` and using the resulting nodes to carry out more queries. I've been doing this within the Neo4j console. For example, using the TinkerGraph dataset:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
==> tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]

gremlin> g.V.getClass()
==> class com.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.GremlinGroovyPipeline

gremlin> m = [:]

gremlin> g.V.out.groupCount(m)
==> v[2]
==> v[4]
==> v[3]
==> v[3]
==> v[5]
==> v[3]

gremlin> m
==> v[2]=1
==> v[4]=1
==> v[3]=3
==> v[5]=1

gremlin> m.getClass()
==> class java.util.LinkedHashMap

gremlin> m = m.keySet()
==> v[2]
==> v[4]
==> v[3]
==> v[5]

gremlin> m.getClass()
==> class java.util.HashMap$KeySet

gremlin> m.outE
==> [StartPipe, OutEdgesPipe]
==> [StartPipe, OutEdgesPipe]
==> [StartPipe, OutEdgesPipe]
==> [StartPipe, OutEdgesPipe]

gremlin> m.outE.map
==> [StartPipe, OutEdgesPipe, PropertyMapPipe]
==> [StartPipe, OutEdgesPipe, PropertyMapPipe]
==> [StartPipe, OutEdgesPipe, PropertyMapPipe]
==> [StartPipe, OutEdgesPipe, PropertyMapPipe]
```

How can I use `m` as a `GremlinGroovyPipeline` object? I am expecting a result similar to this:

```
gremlin> m.outE
==> e[7][1-knows->2]
==> e[8][1-knows->4]
==> e[9][1-created->3]
==> e[12][6-created->3]
==> e[10][4-created->5]
==> e[11][4-created->3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I randomly found the answer on a forum post which was completely unrelated to the question.

Nonetheless, here's the answer:

```
gremlin> m.keySet()_().outE.map
==> {weight=1.0}
==> {weight=0.4}
```

Simply adding the text `_()` after the `keySet()` method call seems to turn it straight back into a `GremlinGrrovyPipeline` object:

```
gremlin> m.keySet()_().getClass()
==> class com.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.GremlinGroovyPipeline
```

Comment: Yes, _() is called the "identity pipe", and it turns normal elements and element collections back into a pipe. Normally you would put a dot between the collection and the identity pipe: `myVertexList._().outE`.